# Skip over element in .map without adding .filter etc

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for beautiful solution
I have array *items*. Item consists of *user_id* and some other information.
I need map all items and for each item find user with appropriate id. Then add to item some information from user

```
items = items.map((item) => {
                let user = users.find(u => item.user_id === u.id);

                item.email = user.email;
                item.user_name = user.name;
                return item;
            });
```

But if user with item.user_id doesn't exist I must do nothing. I already have iterations of two arrays and don't want add more

Comment: Why not `if (!user) return item; `? Or wrap the adding of the information in `if (user)` - whatever.

Comment: @VLAZ - I interpreted "skip over element" as meaning "don't include it in the output array," but I could be wrong about that. @​Natali - Can you clarify that for us?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, that what I meant, don't include it in the output array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "skip over element."

If you mean "don't include it in the output array," then you'll have to put `map` aside, because `map` will always produce an output element for an input element. Instead, you can just loop through pushing to a new array:

```
const originalItems = items;
items = [];
for (const item of originalItems) {
    let user = users.find(u => item.user_id === u.id);
    if (user) {
        item.email = user.email;
        item.user_name = user.name;
        items.push(item);
    }
}
```

If you just mean "don't add the `user` information" (but do keep items you don't add information to), then you can just branch:

```
items = items.map((item) => {
    let user = users.find(u => item.user_id === u.id);
    if (user) {
        item.email = user.email;
        item.user_name = user.name;
    }
    return item;
});
```

That raises the question of why you're using `map` at all, though, since there doesn't immediately seem to be much reason to create a new array with the same objects in it (even if we're adding to those objects). If you're using something like React where state updates must not modify existing objects, you'd want to create a new `item` for any item you changed instead:

```
items = items.map((item) => {
    let user = users.find(u => item.user_id === u.id);
    if (user) {
        item = {
            ...item,
            email: user.email,
            user_name = user.name,
        };
    }
    return item;
});
```

But you may not be doing that, you haven't said.

Comment: yes I meant don't include it in the output array. sorry for being unclear. I just thought that maybe exists some method  without need to use for loop in this case, but thank you very much!

Comment: @Natali - `map` is also a loop. :-) Glad that helped!